# Vapor-compression refrigeration

Tags: thermodynamics

In a vapor-compression refrigeration system I would like to understand the following :

1. Why is there a need for the compressor ? Can't the saturated vapor from the evaporator be cooled directly in the condenser ? Why does it need to be a superheated vapor in order to be condensed ?
2. How an expansion valve works exactly (physically speaking) ? I understand it uses flash evaporation to transform part of the liquid to vapor without heating it. But I don't understand how is this mixture temperature lowered below the temperature of the environment to be cooled. There is some kind of auto-refrigeration that is mentioned in the books I have read that I don't grasp. Can anyone explain to me how this happens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by reading about Carnot cycles and similar thermodynamic engines.

This may help a bit: there's no fast, easy way to cool a vapor to its liquid state.  Once compressed, however, standard radiator technology is quite efficient at extracting heat from the liquid. In addition, since the liquid was heated during compression, it's at a higher temperature than the ambient atmosphere (in the vapor state, it was a lot cooler, so heat transfer would have been very slow).  Large temperature differential means fast heat exchange.

As to expansion: it's one of those facts of the world that free expansion & vaporization of the liquid absorbs energy from the liquid's surroundings -- thus making the surroundings cold, which was the point of the whole system :-) .